# Default selection in sidebar navigation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've built a sidebar navigation on iOS/iPadOS and I'd like to preselect the first sidebar item to avoid presenting empty view on startup.

```
struct SidebarNavigation: View {
    enum Item: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        case inbox = "Inbox"
        case sent = "Sent"
        
        var id: String { rawValue }
        
        var destination: some View { Text(rawValue) }
    }
    
    @State var selection: Item? = .inbox
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(Item.allCases) { item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: item.destination,
                        tag: item,
                        selection: $selection,
                        label: {
                            Text(item.rawValue)
                        })
                }
            }
            
            Text("Select Sidebar Item")
            
            Text("Detail View")
        }
    }
}
```

Launching this on iPad presents following even though `selection` is set to `.inbox`. I've also tried setting `selection` property with `onAppear` modifier on `NavigationView`, but that code only executes when tapping on `Back` button which produces a glitch. Is there a way to solve this or is it a SwiftUI limitation?

[image: Sidebar navigation iPad OS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second view you pass to the `NavigationView` is the destination view you want to use.

I replaced the second `Text` with the destination view, and it now works. I also modified the destination view, to show that this isn't just the same as the `NavigationLink` label.

Working code:

```
struct SidebarNavigation: View {
    enum Item: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        case inbox = "Inbox"
        case sent = "Sent"
        
        var id: String { rawValue }
        
        var destination: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(rawValue)
                
                Text("More content...")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @State var selection: Item? = .inbox
    @State private var tableView: UITableView?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(Item.allCases) { item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: item.destination,
                        tag: item,
                        selection: $selection,
                        label: { Text(item.rawValue) }
                    )
                }
            }
            
            if let selection = selection {
                selection.destination
            }
            
            Text("Detail View")
        }
    }
}
```